# Delete an element in a vector of lists and display the current list

Tags: c++, list, vector, iteration

I am trying to use a vector of lists to store information and then delete the middle item in the lists and print the list again. I am not sure how to access the individual variables of the lists stored in vector, or how to delete the element.

I am trying to delete the element 'puppy' from the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<list<string>> hashT;
    hashT.resize(3);
    int index = 0;

    hashT[0].push_back("hello");
    hashT[0].push_back("Puppy");
    hashT[0].push_back("friend");

    typename list<string>::iterator it = hashT[0].begin();

    for (; it != hashT[0].end(); ++it)
    {
        index = 0;
        //print lists?
        cout << *it;
        //delete puppy?
        hashT[0].erase(hashT[0].begin() + index)
        //print list?
        index++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Current Code-

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<list<string>> hashT;
    hashT.resize(3);
    int index = 0;

    hashT[0].push_back("hello");
    hashT[0].push_back("Puppy");
    hashT[0].push_back("friend");

    typename list<string>::iterator it = hashT[0].begin();

    for (; it != hashT[0].end(); ++it)
    {

        if(*it == "Puppy")
        {
            hashT[0].erase(it);
        }
    }

    typename list<string>::iterator it2 = hashT[0].begin();

        for (; it2 != hashT[0].end(); ++it2)
        {
            cout << *it2;
        }


    return 0;
}
```

It is still printing all 3 values.

Comment: `hashT[0].push_back("hello");` This already exhibits undefined behavior. `hashT` is empty, having no elements. `hashT[0]` accesses an index out of bounds.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I did hashT.resize(3) and now it prints (thanks) how would I delete an element. I'll edit the code for the resize.

Comment: How would you delete *which* element? It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Trying to selete the element puppy from the list

Comment: Having a vector of lists is most certainly a bad idea to begin with. How did you come up with that?

Comment: It is a requirement for a coding assignment. I wrote the code above to simulate the exact problem I am facing in my assignment @BaummitAugen

Comment: Ugh. Might be a good idea to supplement that course with a good C++ book then.

Comment: `if(*it == "Puppy") hashT[0].erase(it);`, and you ought to try erasing an element of a free-standing list, before you attempt to do it with a list in a container.

Comment: Adding in the line of code causes the *it to stop printing.. @Beta

Comment: Because the erasure invalidates the iterator. If you want to keep printing past "Puppy" *in the same loop*, then you must reset the iterator using `index` or a spare iterator.

Comment: The line hashT[0].erase(it) gives an error, no match for operator[] @Beta

Comment: That's odd; it works for me. And you don't get an error from `hashT[0].push_back("hello");`? I suggest you construct an iterator pointing to `hashT[0]`, and see if you can use that instead of invoking `hashT[0]`. If that doesn't work, edit your question to include a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the new problem, and we'll get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Beta i erased it and wrote it again, and the error wen't away. I edited what I currently have, but I am still printing out the entire lists

Comment: Wait a minute... If that line causes a *compiler error*, then how did you run it to discover that it stops the printing?

Comment: I think something went weird with the IDE for a second because I put the line in an if statement and it broke, but not in the if statement it was fine. I just rewrote the if statement and it compiles @Beta

Comment: @Beta wow so I accidentally didn't capatlize puppy, but with that fix in the if statement. *it2 now does not print anything

Comment: The fix was to put a break in the if statement! Thanks so much! @Beta

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<list<string>> hashT;
    hashT.resize(3);


    hashT[0].push_back("hello");
    hashT[0].push_back("Puppy");
    hashT[0].push_back("friend");

    typename list<string>::iterator it = hashT[0].begin();

    for (; it != hashT[0].end(); it++)
    {
        if(*it == "Puppy")
        {
            hashT[0].erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }

    typename list<string>::iterator it2 = hashT[0].begin();

    for (; it2 != hashT[0].end(); ++it2)
    {
        cout << *it2;
    }
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```